# How to get the list of parent items from the list of member items in qt/C++?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a structure -

```
struct uid
{
 quint64 id;
 quint64 parent;
 enum_src src;

};
```

Now, I have a qlist of uid.id. How can I get the list of uid from it?
I don't want to traverse by for loop, etc. Do you have any efficient way to do so?

Comment: How can you get `uid` from `uid.id`? In other word, how are you going to get structure from a number?

Comment: Yes, This is what I want to achieve. Do remember, there is no pointer involved in it. It is just a number that matches with the structure member id.

Comment: Where is the according struct stored? If you have only a number then you cannot magically get a struct from it.

Comment: If you can guarantee that each `id` is unique, you can create a parallel hash table that you can use to retrieve a pointer to the `uid` you're looking for. Complexity is O(1) but the cost is an extra variable to manage and extra memory.

Answer (score 0):

in your example, id is just a number.  YOU need to create something for your program to know that number is an id for a uid.

The only way I can think of to do this without using any "loops, etc." is to store all your uids in a QHash with the id as the key.  So it would be like this:

```
//establish the has that indexes your uids by their id
QHash<quint64, uid> idToUidHash;

uid first;
uid second;
first.id = 1;
second.id = 2;

idToUidHash.insert(1,first);
idToUidHash.insert(2,second);

//Now just get it back out
QList<uid> theUidIWant;
theUidIWant = itToUidHash.values(1);
```

For the record I think this is really ugly code and that you should re-evaluate how your are structuring your data.  I am sorry but I don't feel like I can make any good recommendations without knowing your situation more.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `QMap<quint64,uid>` to store the objects.